# Text on horizontal table line in html

Tags: html, html-table

How can I get below effect?

```
|--- Hello World ---|
|My data            |
|-------------------|
```

I cannot do it in html.

For example I have code:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Nabywca:</td></tr>
  <tr><td><h2>Test test</h2></td></tr>
</table>
```

And I want text "Nabywca:" set like this image:

[image]

It couldn't be in JS, because I want get It into iText HTML parser to generate PDF from HTML.

Comment: with such a vague question, and no code provided I'm guessing you could use css and maybe javaScript by searching in Google.

Comment: Please post the code you are using so we can help, also show us the results that you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20px;">
                <hr/>
            </td>
            <td>Hello World</td>
            <td style="width:20px;">
            <hr/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='3'>My data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4aZHX/1/

** UPDATE **

Based upon your comment, what you are looking for is a Fieldset, not a table.  Try:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>
     Nabywca
  </legend>
  My Data
</fieldset>
```

New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4aZHX/2/

Comment: It is not exactly what I want. Look at my updated question.